# TaxonomyFieldType is not installed properly?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, error, site-template, taxonomy

It is Image library in one SharePoint foundation site, When I am changing its view from Thumbnail to All Item, it is giving following error.

[image]

---

Also, When I am saving site as a template, it is giving

> **Error exporting the list**
>
> Sorry, something went wrong: Error exporting the list named
> "CompanyAnnoucements" at the URL: CompanyAnnoucements TECHNICAL
> DETAILS: Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
> Correlation ID: b270059e-a84e-e06c-462f-77d05095cd09

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Managed metadata service** is not available in SharePoint Foundation. You need to delete the taxonomy fields before you can save the site as a template.

[image]

For more information -

- [SharePoint OnPremise Features](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819267.aspx#bkmk_FeaturesOnPremise)
- [Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/6f4656c7-f308-4b20-9568-19ec1c2c310b/field-type-taxonomyfieldtypemulti-is-not-installed-properly-when-opening-site-columns-page-or-saving?forum=sharepointadmin)